# AngularJS: simulate URL click and rename file to be downloaded

Tags: html, angularjs, file, angularjs-directive, download

I have this dashboard (in angularjs) where you can see some files you uploaded through a custom service. In the interface, every object has its own `file_id` property. The service I use can generate an URL to download the file based on this id, but it's available only for 15 minutes (which is an inconvenient, but I have to work with it).

What I did was the following: when I click on the `Download` button in the interface, I make a call in the back-end to a service that generates a new URL (every time) and then sends it to front-end.

Here, I am trying to simulate a click on that link with the following code:

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'result.' + fileExtension);
downloadLink.setAttribute('href', downloadURI);
downloadLink.click();
```

The download it's working, but the filename is not the desired one (it's a random string - actually a hash that service is using - without an extension) and that can trick the inexperienced users.

Can I do something regarding this? Is there a better method to achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Not all browsers and versions support the `download` attribute. Check that the version of your browser supports it.

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash I tested it with the latest version of Chrome and Mozilla and it does not seem to work. The name of the downloaded file is the name that service saved it with (a hash). I was trying to change it somehow.

Comment: I think you may be out of luck. For security reasons, most browsers do not allow you to change the name of the file using Javascript. Anyway, the user can change the name to whatever they want when they choose a location to download.

Comment: I'll talk with those who made the service, maybe they can do something about it. Yeah, the user can change the filename, but the file can be either csv or json, so they can't know until they open it.
Thanks anyway!